# Check if we have a new record next day

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, days

I have this tale:

| ProductName | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01.02.2020 |
| B | 01.02.2020 |
| A | 02.02.2020 |
| B | 02.02.2020 |
| C | 02.02.2020 |

I want to add a new column that is a binary column, showing `1` for a record that did not exist on a previous day.

For product `C` I should get `1` and for `A` and `B` - `0`:

| ProductName | Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01.02.2020 | 0 |
| B | 01.02.2020 | 0 |
| A | 02.02.2020 | 0 |
| B | 02.02.2020 | 0 |
| C | 02.02.2020 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that for the absolute minimum date you do not want to return `1`. In this case you could use this calculated column formula:

```
Flag = 
VAR _prod = [ProductName]
VAR _date = [Date]
VAR _prod_exists_day_ago = NOT(COUNTROWS(FILTER('TableName', [ProductName] = _prod && [Date] = _date-1)))
RETURN INT(IF([Date] <> MIN([Date]), _prod_exists_day_ago))
```

[image]